# subprocess.Popen and relative directories

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I am writing a script to open notepad.exe using subprocess.Popen()

```
import subprocess 
command = '%windir%\system32\\notepad.exe'
process = subprocess.Popen(command)
output = process.communicate()
print(output[0])
```

This throws a FileNotFoundError

Is it possible to change/add to the above code to make it work with relative paths?
I did try to run the script from C:\Windows> after moving it there, which again failed. Also set the shell=True, but failed as well.
Writing a similar script using os.popen() works ok with relative paths, regardless which directory the script is run from, but as far as I understand popen is not the way forward..

Early steps in the world of programming/Python. Any input much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.path.expandvars` to expand `%windir%`:

```
command = os.path.expandvars('%windir%\\system32\\notepad.exe')
```

The result is a path that then can be passed to `subprocess.Popen`.

`subprocess.Popen` does not expand environment variables such as `%windir%`. The shell might but you really should not depend on `shell=True` to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Pro tip: whenever you get an error asking the system to execute a command, print the command (and, if applicable, the current working directory).  The results will often surprise you.

In your case, I suspect you're just missing a backslash.  Use this instead:

```
command = '%windir%\\system32\\notepad.exe'
```

Before you make that change, try printing the value of `command` immediately after assignment.  I think you'll find the leading "s" in "system" is missing, and that the mistake is obvious.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I did try out both, with \ or \\ in front of system32 but the print was the same.

Answer (score 0):

You could use raw strings to avoid having to double-up your backslashes.

```
command = r'%windir%\system32\notepad.exe'
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if that r the same used in pandas? As in DataFrame.index = DataFrame.index.str.replace(r'(string_to_replace','new_string') ?  I thought it envoked Regular expressions.. but now I think it just denotes raw strings as you wrote. I have seen regular expressions in the form of DataFrame.index.str.replace(r'(\s\.*\)','new_string') hence the confusion..